# Getting the last date from a set of records

Tags: ms-access

********EDITED*********

Basically what I am ultimately looking for is the last appointment a dog was in our shop with details of that appointment. As you know, right now I am just pulling the MAX date, which we have customers that are actually booked out for the entire year, so I am not getting their LAST appointment IN, but their LAST appointment BOOKED in the future.

```
SELECT dbo_Pet.petId, 
         dbo_Pet.petName, 
         dbo_Customer.cstLName, 
         dbo_vwApptGrid.aptDate, 
         dbo_vwApptGrid.aptId, 
         dbo_vwApptGrid.GroomStyle, 
         dbo_vwApptGrid.StatusDescr
FROM (dbo_Customer RIGHT JOIN dbo_Pet ON dbo_Customer.[cstId] = dbo_Pet.[petCustId]) 
         LEFT JOIN dbo_vwApptGrid ON dbo_Pet.petId = dbo_vwApptGrid.aptPetId
WHERE (((dbo_Pet.petId)=[ID]) 
         AND ((dbo_vwApptGrid.aptDate)<=Date()) 
         AND ((dbo_vwApptGrid.aptDate)=(SELECT Max(tMax.aptDate) 
FROM dbo_vwApptGrid As tMax 
WHERE tMax.aptPetId = dbo_Pet.petId)));
```

shows no records at all. If I change max date to greater than today it shows the last booked appointment, like it should. 
Why is this not limiting my max date to less than today??

Comment: Remove AptID, GroomStye, StatusDescr fields. If you need to see the entire record, review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#TopN

Comment: @June7 I got it to work, but edited my question. And thanks for that link!! I've been checking it out, awesome. and there was another link from there that looks really helpful. Big Thanks.

Comment: Instead of HAVING, try WHERE aptDate<=Date().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to go about this, but I prefer filtering by a totals subquery (feels the most descriptive for what I want to me).

The solution commented by @June7 is also valid (especially if you don't need the fields he/she referred to).

When adding additional criteria, always add these to the subquery, never to the main query. If you add them to the main query, you won't get any results, since the subquery will return something that is filtered out.

```
SELECT dbo_Pet.petName
    ,dbo_Customer.cstLName
    ,dbo_vwApptGrid.aptId
    ,dbo_vwApptGrid.aptDate AS most_recent
    ,dbo_vwApptGrid.GroomStyle
    ,dbo_vwApptGrid.StatusDescr
FROM (
    dbo_Customer RIGHT JOIN dbo_Pet ON dbo_Customer.[cstId] = dbo_Pet.[petCustId]
    )
LEFT JOIN dbo_vwApptGrid ON dbo_Pet.petId = dbo_vwApptGrid.aptPetId

WHERE dbo_Pet.petId = [ID] 
AND dbo_vwApptGrid.aptDate = (SELECT Max(tMax.aptDate) FROM dbo_vwApptGrid As tMax WHERE tMax.aptPetId = dbo_Pet.petId AND tMax.aptDate <= Date());
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have edited my question slightly if care to take a look at it again

Comment: Edited to incorporate your extra criterium

Comment: I see the difference. I was thinking I needed to filter out the future dates first to get the max of the remaining dates